# Slack API quote the message

Tags: slack, slack-api

how can I quote a message sent with the Slack api? I couldn't find a method for this function in the documentation. Do you have any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not currently possible to "quote" messages in the same way that the native quote feature does this, but if you include a permalink to the message in the body of the new message, the client should unfurl it for a similar look and feel.

[image: Screenshot of Slack message posted via API with link to existing message]

Comment: can u share code of this method

Comment: https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage

Comment: hi, it doesn't preview when i post the same message 2 times in a row but it previews when I share different messages on top of each other. How can i resolved this

Comment: is any suggestion for iamge review cache for one hour?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making **unfurl_links = true** with **chat.postMessage** method. In order to show the text without a link in the message, **text = Test <www.example.com| >** in url I solved the problem by leaving a space after the **"|"** sign.

Here is ex. cURL:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer xoxb-xxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'channel=#urltest' \
--data-urlencode 'text=*TEST*<https://xx.slack.com/archives/xx/p16547134235899399| >' \
--data-urlencode 'unfurl_links=true'
```

[image]